# Want to populate a Data Extension using Query from another Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, query, journeybuilder, automationstudio

I have 2 Data Extenstion DE1 and DE2.
I want to insert data into DE2 based on conditions of DE1.

Say DE1 has data

```
SID LinkName           
S1  Link1           
S1  Link2           
S2  Link1           
S2  Link2          
S2  Link3         
S3  Link2
```

I want to insert data into a new table DE2 having above Link1, Link2 etc as columns in such a way that if S1 has link 1 then its column for Link1 would show Yes and so on. 
Example for S3, column of Link1 and Link3 will show NO, Link2 Column will show YES

```
SID Link1 Link2 Link3                   
S1  Yes   Yes   No                   
S2  Yes   Yes   Yes                  
S3  No    Yes   No
```

Is it possible using query activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  It'd be something like this, since SFMC doesn't support T-SQL pivot.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    ([SID] varchar(2), [LinkName] varchar(5))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    ([SID], [LinkName])
VALUES
    ('S1', 'Link1'),
    ('S1', 'Link2'),
    ('S2', 'Link1'),
    ('S2', 'Link2'),
    ('S2', 'Link3'),
    ('S3', 'Link2')
;
select 
SID
, max(case when LinkName = 'Link1' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as Link1
, max(case when LinkName = 'Link2' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as Link2
, max(case when LinkName = 'Link3' then 'Yes' else 'No' end) as Link3
from table1
group by SID
```

**Output**

```
| Row | SID | Link1 | Link2 | Link3 |
|-----|-----|-------|-------|-------|
| 1   | S1  | Yes   | Yes   | No    |
| 2   | S2  | Yes   | Yes   | Yes   |
| 3   | S3  | No    | Yes   | No    |
```

Test: **http://rextester.com/SPEYJ40747**

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the reply.
This worked.